# setInterval for css sprite animation

Tags: javascript, css, loops, sprite, setinterval

I'm trying to animate a sprite using the below code but instead of waiting about 1 second before going to the next iteration of the loop, the animation seems to jump from the first image in the sprite to the last within about a second. Can anyone tell me how I might be able to alter the code to make it work the way I have in mind? Thanks!

```
preview = setInterval(animation,1000);
counter = 0; 

function animation() {
    while (counter < 81){
        position = counter * 1.25;
        $('#ad_1').css({"background-position" : position + "% 0%"});
        counter ++;
    }
};

preview;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the while portion of the loop out.

```
function animation() {
    if (counter < 81){
        position = counter * 1.25;
        $('#ad_1').css({"background-position" : position + "% 0%"});
        counter ++;
    } else {
         clearInterval(preview); /* this will stop the interval timer, since you won't need it after 80 repetitions. */
         preview = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your while loop is causing everything to happen in the first interval call. 
Remove it, and you'll be depending solely on intervals:

```
preview = setInterval(animation,1000);
counter = 0; 

function animation() {
        position = counter * 1.25;
        $('#ad_1').css({"background-position" : position + "% 0%"});
        counter ++;        
};

preview;
```

---

Live example:

```js
var preview = setInterval(animation,100);
var counter = 0; 

function animation() {
        position = counter * 1.25;
        $('#ad_1').css({"background-position" : position + "% 0%"});
        counter ++;        
};
```

```css
div {
  height: 317px; 
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2186972673/super_mario.jpg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ad_1"></div>
```